# work with Html::button in Yii 2

Tags: php, html, yii, yii2

i create a gridview in Yii 2 like below :

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider'   => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
            ['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],
            ['class' => 'kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
            'id',
            'countrydate',
            'countryCode'=>[
                'attribute'=>'countryCode',
                'content' => function($model,$key,$index, $column) {
                    return Html::button($model->countryCode,$options = [
                        'onclick'=>'showcountryCode('.$key.')',
                        'id'=>'countryCode'.$key,
                        'class'=>'popup',
                    ]);
                }
            ],
            'countryName',
            'countrydate',
             'population',
             'fipsCode',

        ],
```

and i use my cutson setting for

```
'countryCode'=>[
                    'attribute'=>'countryCode',
                    'content' => function($model,$key,$index, $column) {
                        return Html::button($model->countryCode,$options = [
                            'onclick'=>'showcountryCode('.$key.')',
                            'id'=>'countryCode'.$key,
                            'class'=>'popup',
                        ]);
                    }
                ],
```

you know we can have tags inside eachother in HTML like this :

```
<a> <h1> asdas </h1> </a>
```

now i want to put another tag inside `Html::button` , how should i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Definition of `Html::button()` is

```
public static string button ($content = 'Button', $options = [])
```

so first parameter is anything you want to put inside.

You can use plain HTML

```
Html::button('<b>xxx</b><span>yyyy</span>');
```

or Yii 2 static `Html` methods for the same custom tags:

```
Html::button(Html::tag('b', 'xxx') . Html::tag('span', 'yyyy'));
```